# What's the substitute for ASP.NET Mobile Device Browser File?

Tags: asp.net

Scotty did talk about it http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixMobileWebSitesWithASPNETMVCAndTheMobileBrowserDefinitionFile.aspx and now it'll be gone ?
http://mdbf.codeplex.com/
 This project is no longer supported and will be removed on October 29, 2010

What's the substitute then ? my question is rather why it is abandonned.

Nobody knows ?

Update: weird now the whole codeplex project has been deleted whereas when I asked the question there was content and source code !

> This project is not yet published If
>   you are a coordinator or developer on
>   this project, please sign in to access
>   the project.

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2010/03/05/use-asp.net-4-browser-definitions-with-asp.net-3.5.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a+StephenWalther+%28Stephen+Walther+on+ASP.NET+MVC%29) any help for you? It does target .NET 4.0, not sure if that is an issue for you.

Comment: Hi there. Don't know I'm afraid.

Comment: Seems like it was some secret inside the project has been deleted from codeplex after I ask the question here :)

Answer (score 1):

I would say the replacement is Mobile Device Detection and Redirection found here: http://51degrees.codeplex.com/

I used it for my ASP.NET Web Forms application and it worked great.  Like MDBF, it makes the `Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice` property and other related properties more accurate.

It was very simple to add to my project.  I added the files wurfl.xml.gz and web_browsers_patch.xml to the App_Data folder and added an http module and related configuration settings to the web.config.

Comment: thanks for this resource that's usefull but the one above did seem to do much more, I said did because it has now vanished from codeplex as for the content !